# How to delete every n-th char in file (via batch or vbs)?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, character

How can I delete every n-th (4000th) char (space character) in a file (.txt or .sql)  best via batch or vbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some VBScript, you can't do this with a batch file.
So something like this will do it for you

```
option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim fso 

Dim inFile 
Dim outFile 
Dim buffer 

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set inFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\testIn.txt", ForReading)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\testOut.txt", ForWriting, True)

Do While Not inFile.AtEndOfStream
    buffer = inFile.Read(3999)
    outFile.Write buffer
    If Not inFile.AtEndOfStream Then
        inFile.Read (1)
    End If
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's it :) For the first loop I had to add an offset (since first intervall is about 4023 chars) and now it's working perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still think it is possible with a batch. Although it might depend on what characters can be expected in the files. I might try crafting a batch solution later :)

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Go for it! I'd be interested to see how this could be achieved :)